# Importing and collecting openids

Tags: contacts, import

We use CiviCRM 4.6.9 with Drupal 7, and our members login via OpenID.  No problems there.

However, we have found since we went live about this time last year that the OpenID values are not being populated in the table `civicrm_openid` when they use the site, for example to join as members or make a contribution.  We imported all this data into civicrm_openid for our existing members prior to going live.  The **new** members are all missing this data.

This raises two questions:

1) How do we collect this information as they join as members?  We want this information so that at renewal time we can tell them what their OpenID is in the renewal reminder.

2) How do we import this information into CiviCRM for the members who now are missing this data?  We have the data at hand, associated with their email address.  I tried importing it and it appeared to work, with no errors reported, but checking the data it is still not there.  It seems that for our existing data, each OpenID is associated with a location, but during import a location isn't asked for.  So it seems that this might be a bug.